# can I replace my tablet battery with a phonoe one

Tags: battery

I have a tablet with 3.7v li-ion battery which lasts few minutes on ... 
and an old phone with the same type and voltage battery can I replace tablet battery with this one? and how?

Comment: If the batteries are the same size i.e. the phone's battery fits inside the tablet then it should work. One downside: Tablet batteries usually have bigger capacities which means that your phone's battery won't last as long as a new tablet battery.

Answer (score 0):

If they are literally the same (size ,voltage ,capacity) then it will work just fine